# React: How to show message when result is zero in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-map

How to show **No Result** message when the search result is empty with in `map()` ?

```
export class Properties extends React.Component {
    render () {
        const { data, searchText } = this.props;
        const offersList = data
            .filter(offerDetail => {
                return offerDetail.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
            })
            .map(offerDetail => {
                return (
                    <div className="offer" key={offerDetail.id}>
                        <h2 className="offer-title">{offerDetail.title}</h2>
                        <p className="offer-location"><i className="location-icon"></i> {offerDetail.city}</p>
                    </div>
                );
            });
        return (
            <main>
                <div className="container">
                    <h1>Main {offersList.length}</h1>
                    { offersList }
                </div>
            </main>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: If offersList.length === 0 show No results. else show the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a ternary operator:

```
<main>
   <div className="container">
     <h1>Main {offersList.length}</h1>
     { offersList.length ? offersList : <p>No result</p> }
   </div>
 </main>
```

Answer (score 3):

If `offersList` array is empty, it's length will equal to `0`. You can make easy condition:

```
<div className="container">
  <h1>Main {offersList.length}</h1>
  { offersList.length ? offersList : <p>No Result</p> }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{offersList.length ? (
    // html markup with results
) : (
    // html markup if no results
)}
```