# How to show message when filtered list is empty in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project in which I am trying to show a `div` of content that says *No results found for* if the user types letters in the search input that do not match any filter in the list.  I've tried using this similar solution as reference:  [React: How to show message when result is zero in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225266/react-how-to-show-message-when-result-is-zero-in-react), but without success.

Here is a snippet of my code and one solution (of many) I have tried so far:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      searchQuery: ""
    };
  }

  handleSearchQuery = event => {
    this.setState({ searchQuery: event.target.value });
  };

  resetInputField = () => {
    this.setState({ searchQuery: "" });
  };

  render() {
    const { subContent, type, options, label } = this.props;
    const { searchQuery } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: "grid",
          alignItems: "center",
          width: "100%",
          margin: "0 0 24px 0",
          fontSize: "14px"
        }}
      >
        <div style={sx.rangeInputContainer}>
          <input
            style={sx.rangeInputLong}
            type="text"
            placeholder={placeholderText}
            onChange={this.handleSearchQuery}
            value={searchQuery}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          {options
            .filter(
              option =>
                option.label
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) || !searchQuery
            )
            .map((option, index) => {
              return option.label.length !== 0 ? (
                <div key={index} style={sx.filterOption}>
                  <SquareCheckbox
                    type="checkbox"
                    id={"multiSelectCheckbox-" + option.label}
                  />
                  <label
                    style={{ color: "#FFF" }}
                    htmlFor={"multiSelectCheckbox-" + option.label}
                  >
                    {option.label}
                  </label>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    marginTop: "16px"
                  }}
                >
                  <img
                    style={{ width: "20px", cursor: "pointer" }}
                    src={resetIconSVG}
                    onClick={this.resetInputField}
                  />
                  <div style={{ marginLeft: "16px" }}>
                    No results found for {searchQuery}
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's a snippet of options, which is in my parent component:

```
this.state = {
        filters: [


            {
                label: 'Materials',
                type: FILTER_TYPE.MULTI_SELECT,
                expandedHandle: ()=> {  
                this.handleExpandedToggle('Materials'); },
                options:materials,
                expanded:false,
            },
            {
                label: 'Status',
                type: FILTER_TYPE.SELECT,
                expandedHandle: ()=> {  this.handleExpandedToggle('Status'); 
             },
                options: status,
                expanded:false,
            },


        ],
    };
```

And the dummy .json data I am using:

```
export const materials = [
{ value: 'brass', label: 'brass' },
{ value: 'chrome', label: 'chrome' },
{ value: 'ceramic', label: 'ceramic' },
{ value: 'glass', label: 'glass' },
{ value: 'concrete', label: 'concrete' },

];

export const status = [
{ value: 'Show All', label: 'Show All' },
{ value: 'Enabled Only', label: 'Enabled Only' },

];
```

Comment: "but without success"

Can you be more specific? Is there an error message? Do you get an unexpected result?

Comment: please provide a sample data of `this.props.options`

Comment: I actually get no response.  However if I start the the ternary expression with === 0,  then I see the message *No results found for* repeated four times

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú  I've updated the question with a snippet of my options and dummy json data I am using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made an assumption about your `options` data, hopefully this helps (I simplified the codes)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchQuery: ''
    };
  }
  handleSearchQuery = event => {
    this.setState({ searchQuery: event.target.value });
  };
  resetInputField = () => {
    this.setState({ searchQuery: '' });
  };
  render() {
    const { searchQuery } = this.state;
    const options = [
      { label: 'react' },
      { label: 'angular' },
      { label: 'vue' }
    ];
    const filteredOptions = options.filter(
      option =>
        option.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) ||
        !searchQuery
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleSearchQuery}
            value={searchQuery}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          {filteredOptions.length > 0 ? (
            filteredOptions.map((option, index) => {
              return <div key={index}>{option.label}</div>;
            })
          ) : (
            <div>
              No results found for {searchQuery}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your using a ternary operator inside of a return on your filter method. I would put the filter into a variable

```
const filteredOptions = options.filter(option => option.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) || !searchQuery).map((option, index) => {
  return option.label.length !== 0 ? <div key={index} style={sx.filterOption}>
    <SquareCheckbox type='checkbox' id={'multiSelectCheckbox-' + option.label} />
    <label style={{ color: '#FFF' }} htmlFor={'multiSelectCheckbox-' + option.label}> {option.label} </label>
  </div> })
```

and in your render use the ternary to check the length of the array

```
render {
 return (
  {filteredOptions.length > 0 ? filteredOptions : <div style = {{ marginLeft: '16px' }}>No results found for { searchQuery }</div>}
  )
}
```